# Redirect after loading images

Tags: javascript, redirect, wait

So I have been recently developing a site, The problem is the backgrounds for each page are images, and as a result, on slower connections (which is the case of some of the target audience) the images load progressivly as they are downloaded, to resolve this I am trying to make a preloading page that does the following :

- Loads the Images
- Once the loading is done, redirects the user to the requested page

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
      var images = new Array()
      var count=0;
      function preload() {
          for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
              images[i] = new Image()
              images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
          }
      if(count==4) {
      window.location = "index.html";
      }
      }
      preload(
          "backgrounds/bg1.jpg",
          "backgrounds/bg2.jpg",
          "backgrounds/bg3.jpg",
          "backgrounds/bg4.jpg"
      )
  //--><!]]>
  ```

The problem is it redirects directly (I assume that it just starts the download of the image then directly adds one to the counter variable, quickly reaching 4 and not giving the image the time to download.

Any ideas how I can either make it signal me when the images have finished downloading, or only execute the redirect after it has done downloading the images ?

Comment: How long does it take to download all of these images? If it takes more than a couple seconds, you're going to start to lose visitors after 3s, with a rapidly-increasing share of desertions for every second after that. Additionally, this is going to cause issues with SEO, if you don't do something to accomodate crawlers. Just a heads-up that this may not be the path you should be looking for, for a modern web design, unless this is some kind of art-piece where you're less concerned with keeping an audience.

Comment: Hey Mori, They take up to 5 seconds to download, SEO wise, if they don't pass JS (noscript) they are auto redirected to the homepage, I have also provided them with my sitemap, don't know if that will help ?

Comment: That's a hazardous path. Most people want to reduce their page load times... you're actively delaying page load times just to make some background images viewable. Remember that progressive loading JPGs were invented to reduce the amount of time it takes for a user to get to what they want (content) while the UI loads in at the speed the user's connection can allow... intentionally defeating that will cost visitors. Articles: http://www.userintelligence.com/ideas/blog/2012/08/slow-websites-can-cost-you-money and http://www.slideshare.net/stelianfirez/a-little-journey-into-website-optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the `load` event. It's quite simple:

```
function preload(images, timeout, cb) {
  var cbFired = false,
      remaining = images.length,
      timer = null;

  function imageDone() {
    remaining--;

    if(remaining === 0 && !cbFired) {
      cbFired = true;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      cb();
    }
  }

  function timerExpired() {
    if(cbFired)
      return;

    cbFired = true;
    cb();
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = imageDone;
    img.onerror = imageDone;
    img.src = images[i];
  }

  timer = setTimeout(timerExpired, timeout);
}
```

You need to check a few things so that users don't get stuck:

- You need to wait for both `load` and `error` so that the page doesn't get stuck if an image fails to load.
- You should set a maximum timeout.
- Also, in your code, `i` was a global variable (no `var` declaration).

Here's how to use it:

```
var images = [ "backgrounds/bg1.jpg",
    "backgrounds/bg2.jpg",
    "backgrounds/bg3.jpg",
    "backgrounds/bg4.jpg"];

preload(images, 10000 /* 10s */, function () {
  window.location = 'next_page';
});
```

Comment: Superb ! Thankyou very much, This Works a treat ! thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Modify your preloader so that it binds to the "onload" event of the Image object and when all callbacks are fired it redirects (untested sample code below):

```javascript
var images = new Array()
var count = 0;
function preload() {
    var numImages = preload.arguments.length
    for (i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].onload = doneLoading; // See function below.
        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
    }
    function doneLoading() {
        if (++count >= numImages) {
            window.location = "index.html";
        }
    }
}
preload(
    "backgrounds/bg1.jpg",
    "backgrounds/bg2.jpg",
    "backgrounds/bg3.jpg",
    "backgrounds/bg4.jpg"
)
```